# How do I create a new instance of a different class when saving a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Class A that when it is instantiated and saved for the first time or modified it will create an instance of Class B and save it also

I want them to be in the same transaction and I want it to be handled in the Model not a controller.

I know how to do this in a conteoller with the ‘transaction do’  block but how do I do it in the model?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in an `after_save` callback, which is in the same transaction as the original save. See the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html).

Comment: Cool, I just did not realize it was the same transaction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use models callbacks such as before_save or before_create etc

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks